# Macmini running osX 10.7 when I log out it says connection to xxx closed

Tags: mac-osx

When I log out of my macmini server using terminal it says

"Connection to www.kannhost.co.uk closed"

www.kannhost.co.uk is one of the domains that I host and have set up using vhosts.php

How can I change the name of the server to show the following

"Connection to macmini closed"

Comment: Are you connecting to the system by name or IP address?  And what reverse DNS is set up for the IP address that you're connecting to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the current machine you're using, modify the [hosts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29) file to point the term "macmini" to the IP for www.kannhost.co.uk.

Next time you connect, shell in to "macmini" (not www.kannhost.co.uk) and you'll get the message you want when you disconnect.